# Segmentation Fault using double pointers

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm getting segmentation fault while handling wit**h** double pointer in the below code. I've spent way too much time and couldn't find what the error was.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int *p,**pp,n=2;
    p=new int;
    pp=&p;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>*(*(pp+i))>>*(*(pp+i)+1);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<*(*(pp+i))<<" "<<*(*(pp+i)+1)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Not sure if this is a noob question.

Comment: you allocate space for a single `int`. It is not clear what you expect where `pp+i` points to

Comment: undefined behaviour times undefined behaviour is still undefined ;). What is the code actually supposed to do? Seems like you want an array or vector and someone made you believe you need pointers for that (you dont)

Comment: You're treating your pointers as if they were pointing to array elements, but there are no arrays in your code. (Remember that arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays.)

Comment: And your code crashes quite "reliably", because pp is pointer to pointer, and you use it like it pointed to array of pointers, and get pointer from index 1 of that non-existent array. This gives you garbage value, which you then dereference. A garbage pointer is likely (but not certain at all, can't trust this) to cause segmentation fault on a modern OS with memory protection. Of course it could cause you program to do many other things too, because the behavior is Undefined...

Comment: Oh, thanks guys I wanted pp to work as an array. So, double pointer cannot solely be treated as an array without actually pointing it to one? If so, I get it.

Comment: Wanted a[n][2].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
int *p, **pp, n = 2;
p = new int[n * 2];
pp = &p;

for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
    cin >> *(*pp + n*i + i) >> *(*pp + n*i + i + 1);
for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
    cout << *(*pp + n*i + i) << " " << *(*pp + n*i + i + 1) << endl;

delete []p;
return 0;
```

Comment: nobody **needs** something like that, unless they are one step towards becoming a [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: @user463035818 But maybe this is what he needs? Do not need to be afraid of three stars: it's magic and only)

Comment: I cannot think of a requirement that would make it necessary to write such code. If OP wants an array or vector they should use an array or vector, instead of writing unnecessarily obscure code.

Comment: there is not even the hint of a reason to use `pp`. Also in your code you use `pp` only to derefernce it. Nothing would be missing (apart from some obscurity) if you removed `pp` entirely